# Installing different versions of MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I would like to know if it's possible to install different versions of MonoDevelop on the same computer.

Currently, I have MonoDevelop 5.7 running on a Ubuntu 14.04.

I did some research and it seems that the 'Deploy to Web' is gone from this version of MonoDevelop. So, I thought that I could install a different version of MonoDevelop so that I could use the 'Deploy to Web' function that existed in previous versions, like 5.0.

Does anyone know how could I solve this problem? Is it possible to install different versions?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.